# PHP get the email that was filled in and send a message to that email?

Tags: php, email

So what I want to do is get the email they filled the forum in with and then send a message to that email they filled in here's what I have: it says its sent but I never get the message:

```
 <?php
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $message = $_POST['message'];
       $from = 'From: My Contact Form';
       $to = '$email';
       $subject = 'Folio Message';

       $body = "Hello";



       if ($_POST['submit']) {
           if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
           echo '<center><font color="lightgray"><p>Message Sent Successfully!</p><script type="text/javascript"> function leave() { window.location = "http://webdesign.about.com"; } setTimeout("leave()", 3000); </script></center>';
           } else {
           echo '<center><font color="lightgray"><p>Ah! Try again, please?</p></font></center>';
           }
       }
    ?>
```

So i have `$to = '$email';` so by doing that it should read the email that was filled in right? Idk my PHP skills are weak 
any idea's? or advice? 
Thank you in advance kind people!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the apostrophes from the **$to = '$email';**

It should be **$to = $email;**

With the apostrophes, your **$to** variable is being set to the string "$email" and not the email that the user entered.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the single quotes around `$email`, so your code looks like this: `$to = $email;`.

PHP evaluates content in single quotes as a literal string, without interpreting any variables.  So, it is literally using the text `$email` as the recipient's email address.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

1. `From` header should contain valid mail address. E.g.

   ```
   $from = 'From: youraddress@domain.com';
   ```
2. As others said fix the single quotes. You can just use `$email` in `mail` call like

   ```
   mail ($email, $subject, $body, $from)
   ```

On a different note, consider sanitizing your POST parameters. Especially if your script is on publicly available site.